# Syncronizing Async Tasks Across Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Trying to figure out the best way to architect a solution for this problem

HTTP Request Pipeline when Handling Authentication Middleware. runs OnTokenValidated in the JwtBearerOptions is executed in parallel to my requests code.  I could run this synchronously but I would prefer not to,

Some of my request Require this claim, how can I be assure that this claim has been set?

1. I'm running two threads parallel,
2. one async function is dependent on the other thread to set a variable
3. I created an await manager to get my task.
4. However, There is a chance the await manager has not set the key for task because i didn't execute.

My code:

```
public class TaskManager : ITaskManager
{

    Dictionary<string, Task> _taskAwaiterMap = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
    public Task GetTaskForKey(string key)
    {
        this._taskAwaiterMap.TryGetValue(key, out var awaiter);
        return awaiter;
    }

    public void QueueTask(string key, Task task)
    {
        this._taskAwaiterMap[key] = task;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```
public async Task GetManditoryTaskForKey(string key, int timeout)
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
    await GetManditoryResolverWaitTask(key, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}

protected async Task<Task> GetManditoryResolverWaitTask(string key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (false == this._taskAwaiterMap.TryGetValue(key, out var task))
    {
        if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return Task.FromCanceled(cancellationToken);
        }
        await Task.Yield();
    }

    return this.GetTaskForKey(key);
}
```

I've figure out a way to await for my key to be set but is the an efficient way for synchronizing async tasks?

**EDIT**

In my Http Pipe Line I would Queue a task like so:

```
OnTokenValidated = async tvc => { await AuthenticationRule.ValidateToken(tvc); }

//... Source ValidateToken
//Some Potentially long Task
var awaitManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITaskManager>();
var userClaimsTask = SetUserClaims(claimsIdentity, context, userSubjectId);    
awaitManager.QueueTask(USER_CLAIM_AWAITER_KEY, userClaimsTask);
```

How can I efficiently synchronize my async Tasks?

Comment: You can use `TaskCompletionSource` to let one execution flow wake up a different one using TPL.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks, do you have an informaton or resource I can use to start my research on how to do so?

Comment: This question does not appear materially different from [the one you posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534312/syncronizing-async-tasks-on-seperate-threads). Please figure out which one you actually want answered and delete the other. Note that both of these are, however, still too broad. You have not simplified the scenario nor created a _complete_ code example that illustrates that simplified scenario. As things stand, there are too many possible answers with no way to know which one(s) would be acceptable to you.

Comment: @PeterDuniho sorry that question was meant to be deleted. I was only using part of the text for reference

Comment: If you have one thread waiting on another, then do you really need two threads? Is there a different way you can break down the problem so that there arent any dependencies between the two threads? It would be helpful to see the code for actual problem.

Comment: @MikeHixson,  I'm not in control of the threads, this is naturally caused by the HTTP Request Pipeline when Handling Authentication Middleware.  My code is just setting a claim on the HTTP Context from the Authentication Middleware, and I need to wait on that claim from the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to answer your previous question. :)

Anyway, I am not certain that this is the best solution for your problem because I am not familiar with the Async HTTP pipeline. But the following can be a solution for the approach you are taking:

```
public class TaskManager : ITaskManager
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<Task>> _taskAwaiterMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<Task>>();

    public async Task GetTaskForKey(string key)
    {
        await await this._taskAwaiterMap.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new TaskCompletionSource<Task>()).Task;
    }

    public void QueueTask(string key, Task task)
    {
        this._taskAwaiterMap.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new TaskCompletionSource<Task>()).SetResult(task);
    }
}
```

I assume TaskManager will only live within the session. Otherwise, you will have to think of how to clean up `_taskAwaiterMap`.

Comment: @llianPinzon Thank you for finding this thread again, this looks perfect I need to test this out

Comment: @johnny5 Fixed a bug in `GetTaskForKey`. Note the two awaits.

Comment: @llianPinzon, How can I be sure that the Key has been set for this?

Comment: `GetTaskForKey` will create a non-completed TaskCompletionSource for the given key even if `QueueTask` has not been called yet. That's the purpose for `GetOrAdd`. But only `QueueTask` can complete the TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: @johnny5 Essentially, `GetTaskForKey` will create the key if it isn't there yet.

Comment: @llianPinzon, yeah but won't that just be an task? how does it know to wait for the Key to be set afterwards?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164227/discussion-between-ilian-pinzon-and-johnny-5).

Comment: @llianPinzon, Hey quick question, why are you passing a lambda to the getOrAdd instead of the TaskCompletionSource Directly

Comment: I just prefer that overload because I don't want to create an instance of TaskCompletionSource unless it's really needed. I suspect that constructing TaskCompletionSource may not be that heavy though. So it probably does not matter performance-wise.

Comment: Okay just checking, I'm implementing a timeout on there, I just wasn't sure if the func was required